# Java Agent support for lower version target JVM

Tags: java, bytecode

I am currently working on Dynamic Java ByteCode Agent using Instrumentation API and observed that Java Agent written on Java 11 is only able to attach itself with JVM 11 and not with any lower version of java applications. To elaborate the case here, i am mentioning two scenario.

**Scenario 1** I have developed two APIs on java 11 as producer and consumer and deployed on Apache tomcat 9(tomcat is running on JAVA 11). To test byte code injection, I started agent which is running on Java 11, and found that agent is able to attach itself with the running JVM.

**Scenario 2** I have deployed consumer and producer application compile on Java 8 on Apache tomcat 8.5 (tomcat is running on JAVA 8). I started agent which is running on Java 11, and this time agent threw exception as shown below

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/test/instrumentation/agent/TestAgent has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), 
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

```java
VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach("some java process id");
String  filePath = "C:\\test\\testagent-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar";
vm.loadAgent(filePath, "some string");
vm.detach();
```

The problem I am getting is while calling `vm.loadAgent(filePath,"some string")`

I understand that this error is related to the Version mismatch but my requirement is such that i need to be able to attach any JVM irrespective of their version. Does any one has any work around for this problem?

Comment: it looks like you somewhere loaded `TestAgent` class using java 8, not related at all the the agent issue

Comment: That’s like with any other Java software. If you want to support Java 8, compile with `--release 8`. Or use a JDK 8 in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you will compile agent using java 8 then you will be able to use it for any app in java 8+. As agent should be possible to load at target VM. So you should use lowest needed version for compilation.
And best to run the agent injector from same version as target application, but attaching agent loads agent to target jvm anyway, so it should not matter too much.